# SSIS Connector for Azure File Storage

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-storage

I have a directory on a local machine that holds various source files containing data that I need to load into an Azure SQL Server instance. The source files are in a variety of formats including xlsx, xls, csv, txt, dat. I built a solution a while back that transforms and loads these files into a local sql server and ssis instance (developers edition).

Now that development has concluded I would like to deploy the db and packages to Azure. With an Azure account I created SQL Server and SSIS instances, then I created a file storage account in Azure and copied the source file directory into the file store. My intention was that I would be able to simply take the old solution, change the sources from local files to an Azure data lake store source and the destinations from local db to the Azure Sql instance.

However, I am having a lot of complications with active directory authentication and it also appears that the datalake and blob source tools in SSIS only work for text and azro files. Is there not a ways for SSIS to easily access files in an Azure file store?